# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at share-modal.js:1:135 (anonymous)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I am creating a weather app using HTML CSS And Javascript and i keep getting this error of a null eventlistener which i don't even
have in my DOM.

```
document.querySelector(".tui-image-editor-main-container .tui-image-editor-download-btn").addEventListener("click", (t=>{
    t.preventDefault(),
```

//this line shows the error

```
incrementCounter = void setTimeout((function() {
   document.querySelector(".tui-image-editor-main-container .tui-image-editor-download-btn").addEventListener("click", (t=>{
        t.preventDefault(),
        chrome.storage.local.get(["openTimes", "rateClicked"], (function(t) {
            let {openTimes: n, rateClicked: o} = t;
            n ? n += 1 : n = 1,
            chrome.storage.local.set({
                openTimes: n
            }),
            o || n % 4 != 0 || document.getElementById("xxdialog-rate") || (document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", e),
            function() {
                for (var e = document.querySelectorAll("[i18n]"), t = 0; t < e.length; ++t)
                    e[t].textContent = chrome.i18n.getMessage(e[t].getAttribute("i18n"));
                for (e = document.querySelectorAll("[i18n-alt]"),
                t = 0; t < e.length; ++t) {
                    var n = chrome.i18n.getMessage(e[t].getAttribute("i18n-alt"));
                    e[t].alt = n,
                    e[t].title = n
                }
            }(),
            document.querySelector("#xxdialog-yes").addEventListener("click", (function() {
                chrome.storage.local.set({
                    rateClicked: !0
                }),
                document.getElementById("xxdialog-rate").remove(),
                window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/" + chrome.runtime.id + "/reviews", "_blank").focus()
            }
            )),
            document.querySelector("#xxdialog-no").addEventListener("click", (function() {
                document.getElementById("xxdialog-rate").remove()
            }
            )))
        }
        ))
    }
    ));
    const e = '\n<div id="xxdialog-rate" class="xxflex-container">\n    <div class="xxdialog">\n      <h2 class="xxdialog-header" i18n="rateDialogTitle"></h2>\n      <div class="xxdialog-content">\n        <p i18n="rateDialogDesc"></p>\n      </div>\n      <div class="xxdialog-button">\n        <a href="#" id="xxdialog-yes" class="xxcancel" i18n="rateDialogYes"></a>\n        <a href="#" id="xxdialog-no" i18n="rateDialogNo"></a>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n'
}
), 300);
```

there is nothing available about this error on the internet.

Comment: The error means that a `querySelector()` call is returning `null`, meaning that the element you are looking for is not in the DOM.

Comment: *which i don't even have in my DOM* — right, so if it's not in your DOM you will get that exception.

Comment: The file in which the error is `share-model.js` is not created by me.

Comment: OK, well tell whoever created it that it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

remove the screen shot chrome add-on on your browser, the error message comes from the extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).